# How do I use the SafariViewController in Objective-c?

Tags: ios, objective-c

Apple rejected my app today suggesting, among other things, I shouldn't force my users out to Safari to visit my web page. They suggested using SafariWebController which is new in iOS9. I went searching for guidance and only found Swift tutorials.

I had been using the following to launch Safari, associated with a button:

```
NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:WEBSITE_REGISTRATION_URL];
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:url];
```

So, I'll share my simple configuration for those of us trying to keep up who are not yet on Swift.

Answer (score 53):

There are 5 steps:

1. Click on your project target and then select "Build Phases". Under "Build Phases", click on the arrow by "Link Binary with Libraries" and click the plus. Search for SafariServices in the window that will open. Highlight it in the list and click "Add".
       [image]
2. Import the library into .m file where your button resides:

   ```
   #import <SafariServices/SafariServices.h>
   ```
3. Define a class extension in your .m file to conform to Safari VC protocol:

   ```
   @interface SKWelcomeViewController () <SFSafariViewControllerDelegate>
   ```
4. Implement the following delegate method that will be called when the Safari View Controller needs to be dismissed dismissed:

   ```
   - (void)safariViewControllerDidFinish:(SFSafariViewController *)controller {
       [self dismissViewControllerAnimated:true completion:nil];
   }
   ```
5. And finally, the code inside the IBAction:

   ```
   SFSafariViewController *svc = [[SFSafariViewController alloc] initWithURL:url];
   svc.delegate = self;
   [self presentViewController:svc animated:YES completion:nil];
   ```

Enjoy!

Comment: @Julian, I'm not following you. What are you referring to?

Comment: In step 3, why do you add `SFSafariViewControllerDelegate` in the .h file? Do the clients of your `SKWelcomeViewController` class need to know that the `SKWelcomeViewController` class works with `SFSafariViewController`?

Comment: In step 4, why do you add this `delegate` property? Are clients of your `SKWelcomeViewController` going to make themselves the `delegate`?

Comment: Great questions @rmaddy. Step 4 is not necessary. Thank you. And, I have an embarrassingly ignorant answer for your question about Step 3...because it works. I'm open to suggestions and fully admit to having a poor understanding of delegates.

Comment: For step 3, you should declare that you conform to the protocol using the class extension in the .m file. This way it's done privately. The .h file should only have things that are meant to be public.

Comment: @SteveSTL: Step 4. It works. But you don't use the property. You don't assign anything to it at any point. It works because its obsolete. It will work exactly the same, when you remove it. To be honest, this is just a coding mistake.

Comment: @Julian, right you are. Very nice. Thanks. And, for anyone coming to the party late...ignore the step numbers in the comments. Julien edited and removed the unnecessary/incorrect bits.

Comment: Thank you for the import statement in step 2, couldn't find much documentation for this.

Comment: Note that step `three` and `four` is not required if you wish to leave the safari view open.

Comment: I got a crash with this error: Application tried to present a nil modal view controller on target. Safari VC is displaying as null

Comment: Will that safari controller cache the web pages?